# Provisioning Profile invalid when creating Push Certification SSL in iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

Every time I create a push notification ssl on my app the provisioning profile for that app suddenly became invalid. Is anyone experiencing my problem too?

Answer (score 0):

Please check .p12 certificates and try to reinsatll